# Flutter GetX bindings?

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-dependencies, dart-pub, flutter-getx

Iam new to this architecture, I have a doubt regarding the bindings in getX

I have two controllers cartController and splashController
I need this cartController to remain its state as for the entire lifecycle of app
splashController only for the splashScreen

But the splash controller only works when I bind it with other controllers in initial binding in GetMaterialApp

```
GetMaterialApp(
      home: const SplashScreen(),
      initialBinding: RootBinding(),
      getPages: [
        GetPage(
          name: SplashScreen.routeName,
          page: () => const SplashScreen(),
        ),
        GetPage(
            name: HomeScreen.routeName,
            page: () => const HomeScreen(),
            children: [
              GetPage(
                name: CategoryScreen.routeName,
                page: () => const CategoryScreen(),
              ),
              GetPage(
                name: AboutScreen.routeName,
                page: () => const AboutScreen(),
              ),
              GetPage(
                name: CartScreen.routeName,
                page: () => const CartScreen(),
              ),
            ]),
      ],
    );
```

Root binding is

```
class RootBinding implements Bindings {
  @override
  void dependencies() {
    Get.put<SplashController>(SplashController());
    Get.put<HomeController>(HomeController());
    Get.put<CategoryController>(CategoryController());
    Get.put<AboutController>(AboutController());
  }
}
```

It also doesn't work when i change it to Get.lazyPut()

I dont know if this is the best practise the above code works but when i remove a controller from initial binding to a page it doesnt work like below

```
GetPage(
   name: SplashScreen.routeName,
   page: () => const SplashScreen(),
   binding: SplashBinding()
   ),
```

link to source code
https://github.com/shabhi1997/GetXBaseProject/tree/master

Answer (score 2):

you can use the **BindingsBuilder** callback.
Whenever you visit Splash Screen, Getx will create an instance of Splash controller, and as soon as the page will be removed from **stack**, GetX automatically removes the instance of splash screen controller.

```
GetPage(
   name: SplashScreen.routeName,
   page: () => const SplashScreen(),
   binding: BindingsBuilder(() {
          Get.lazyPut<SplashController>(
            () => SplashController(),
          );
        }))
```

Answer (score 1):

I have done similar thing hoping this helps

When you are navigating user to HomeScreen after Splash Screen you can navigate using **Get.offAll()** with Bindings in which **you have initialised all your controllers**

Navigating to the HomeScreen

```
Get.offAll(
  () => const InitialScreen(screenTag: appControllersTag),
  binding: InitialScreenBindings(tag: appControllersTag),
)
```

Initialising all controllers

```
class InitialScreenBindings implements Bindings {
  String tag;

  InitialScreenBindings({required this.tag});

  @override
  void dependencies() {
    Get.lazyPut(() => BottomNavigationController(), tag: tag);
    Get.lazyPut(() => HomeController(), tag: tag);
    Get.lazyPut(() => OrderController(), tag: tag);
    Get.lazyPut(() => CartController(), tag: tag);
    Get.lazyPut(() => ProfileController(), tag: tag);
  }
}
```

with this my BottomNavigationController, HomeController, OrderController, CartController and ProfileController is alive in entire lifecycle of app

Quick Suggestion:
You can **inject controllers with tags**, believe me it makes your life easy as it helps in debugging and fixing issues.

Answer (score 0):

In case of cartController just make the permanent flag:true in Get.put() method to keep it alive in whole app Cycle.

Also remove home: const SplashScreen(). This is causing the main issue. Your splashScreen is being created without its bindings(Controllers).

Instead,While declaring routes of application give SplashScreen route name '/' which means initial route. It will automatically initialise at the start .You won't need to provide it in initial binding.